# React js download file problem with firefox mobile

Tags: javascript, file, firefox, download, srt

I have the following code which allows me to create a `.srt` file to be able to download it later.

It seems to work fine, but when I use `Firefox` on android device, the file does download but the file format is not correct, it should be `.srt` instead it is `.txt`.

It seems to only happen with `Firefox` on android, on pc it seems to give no problems.

Where am I doing wrong?

```js
const element = document.createElement("a");
const file = new Blob([value], { type: "text/plain" });
element.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
element.download = name + num + ".srt";
document.body.appendChild(element); // Required for this to work in FireFox
element.click();
```

Comment: Try just `new Blob([value]);` to create the blob.

Comment: I tried, same problem.

Comment: does it work with a manually click? maybe a security mechanism by the browser?

Comment: I click on a button, which should make me download the file.